# Best way for ASP.NET MVC5 localization where locale is passed in querystring with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, attributerouting

A very long title, sorry for that.

I'm looking for your input on the best way to support localization in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project in which i would like to pass the locale as part of the querystring. This way it would be easy for users to share a link to website and also pass the correct locale as part of the link.

If this would be done using, for example cookies, the user would pass a link but the page might be in a different language for the person who receives the link. I don't think that that is very nice.

The solution i currently use (http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) does not work nice with incorrect urls and just keeps loading the same page in loop. There is a lot of information on the web and i already went through a lot but i would like to know what is most commonly used and really works well.

As a bonus i would like the solution to work with attribute routing as my current solution doens't play nice :(

Comment: please note that by `Google Multi-regional and Multilingual` document it is discouraged to use language in the query string. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en
funny thing, since they use it in the url themselfs :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use resource files for that, the current culture is in the current thread of the web request, so no need to pass it in the querystring but it can be done;

have a look at this live demo: http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com

you can download/read pdf about it here: http://prodinner.codeplex.com

you can see there that you can change the language using the dropdown; 
in Global.asax.cs Application_BeginRequest, there's already code in there related to language, it reads a cookie now (or it's absence), you can make it read the querystring